# JetBrains Intellij IDEA not showing Java module. It only shows Groovy in Java project

Tags: java, groovy, intellij-idea

I am using IDEA community edition and I have jdk1.7 installed. The problem is that I cant choose Java project in the New Project windows of IDEA. When I select Java in the project window it only shows Groovy. I want to switch from NetBeans to IDEA. Netbeans worked perfectly on my system. Is their any configuration error ?

[The image of New Project Window](http://postimg.org/image/sjs37qu73/)

Answer (score 4):

Just click on "next" and don't select Groovy :)
It then should create the Java Project you want.

Groovy is optional, thats why IntelliJ is asking you if you want it, and if you don't want it just click next and proceed with the next page (and if the next page is also nothing you want just hit "next" again, you have to to this 2 or 3 time till you get to name the project :D)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) first.

Then open IntelliJ IDEA, create a new project, click `New` => `JDK` next to "Project SDK":

[image: IntelliJ IDEA New Project]

Then select the directory of the JDK just installed:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Select Home Directory for JDK]

Now just click `Next` in the New Project window, and you can start working with standard Java.